# How to find relationship between two distribution curves

Tags: matlab, math, regression, mathematical-optimization

I have some floating data (represented by blue curve), when I do some loss compression, the yellow curve can be obtained (mean,standard deviation).

My aim is to minimize this losses **after compression process**, Hence, I would like to find an **equation/curve/filter** that:

> the yellow curve  times "function" nearly equal to blue Gaussian curve.

or

> blue curve = Function(green curve)

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do Kolmogorov–Smirnov test. It compares the maximum difference between the cumulative distributions of the two input vectors.

You can start to play with this test using the implementation in Matlab called `[h p k]=kstest2(dist1, dist2)` You should be looking at the k value which is the test statistic, it denotes the maximum difference between the 2 empirical cumulative distributions. If you want to visualise how is this difference calculated,

```
cdfplot(dist1)
hold on
cdfplot(dist2)
```

hold off
you will see the two cumulative distributions in the same plot. The maximum differene between them is k. If the relationship between the 2 distributions are high the lower the gap is and k value tends to be 1 and in case of highly different distributions the value moves towards 0 and away from 1. 
Hope it helps.
If you have found any more interesting methods, kindly let me know.